# What's Wrong With this minimax algorithm

Tags: java, minimax

I have no idea what the problem is .I printed the moveVal all the time it prints 0 and its going in a horizontal order.

The I have been editing a changing the code by using Google and YouTube but, there was no good

```
static class Move {
    int row, col;
}
private boolean equals(JButton a, JButton b, JButton c){
    return a.getText().equals(b.getText()) && b.getText().equals(c.getText()) && !a.getText().equals("");
}
private boolean isGameOver() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (equals(board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (equals(board[0][i], board[1][i], board[2][i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (equals(board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2])) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (equals(board[2][0], board[1][1], board[0][2])) {
        return true;
    }
    int openSpots = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (board[i][j].getText().equals("")) {
                openSpots++;
            }
        }
    }
    return openSpots == 0;
}
private int evaluate(JButton[][] b) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        if (b[row][0] == b[row][1] &&
                b[row][1] == b[row][2])
        {
            if (b[row][0].getText().equals(ai))
                return 20;
            else if (b[row][0].getText().equals(human))
                return -10;
        }
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
        if (b[0][col] == b[1][col] &&
                b[1][col] == b[2][col])
        {
            if (b[0][col].getText().equals(ai))
                return 20;

            else if (b[0][col].getText().equals(human))
                return -10;
        }
    }
    if (b[0][0] == b[1][1] && b[1][1] == b[2][2])
    {
        if (b[0][0].getText().equals(ai))
            return 20;
        else if (b[0][0].getText().equals(human))
            return -10;
    }
    if (b[0][2] == b[1][1] && b[1][1] == b[2][0])
    {
        if (b[0][2].getText().equals(ai))
            return 20;
        else if (b[0][2].getText().equals(human))
            return -10;
    }
    return 0;
}
private int minimax(JButton[][] position, int depth, boolean isMax) {
    if (isGameOver() || depth == 0){
        return evaluate(position);
    }
    
    else if (isMax)
    {
        int best = -1000000000;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (position[i][j].getText().equals(""))
                {
                    position[i][j].setText(ai);
                    JButton[][] position1 = position;
                    best = Math.max(best, minimax(position1, depth - 1, false));
                    System.out.println(best);
                    position[i][j].setText("");
                }
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
    else
    {
        int best1 = 1000000000;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (position[i][j].getText().equals(""))
                {
                    position[i][j].setText(human);
                    JButton[][] position1 = position;
                    best1 = Math.min(best1, minimax(position1, depth - 1, true));
                    position[i][j].setText("");
                }
            }
        }
        return best1;
    }
}
private void BestMove(JButton[][] board) {
    int bestVal = -1000000000;
    Move bestMove = new Move();
    bestMove.row = -1;
    bestMove.col = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j].getText().equals(""))
            {
                board[i][j].setText(ai);
                int moveVal = minimax(board, 3, false);
                board[i][j].setText("");
                
                if (moveVal > bestVal)
                {
                    bestVal = moveVal;
                    bestMove.row = i;
                    bestMove.col = j;
                    
                }  
            }
        }
    }
    board[bestMove.row][bestMove.col].setText(ai);
    playersTurn = true;
    CheckWinner();
}
```

Any ideas & ***please*** help is needed
past 3 days I have been debugging I know this code is not the best in fact this code might be the worst you have ever seen.

> Blockquote

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a lot of code you're asking us to debug for you.  In your own debugging efforts, what have you narrowed down?  As you step through the execution of the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  Help us to help you by providing more specific indications of the problem.  To learn more about how to ask an answerable question, please see [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

You have only 3 possible evaluations:

- 20, if the AI wins
- -10, if the human wins
- 0, in all other cases

As you only look at 4 turns (ai, human, ai, human), it's impossible to find a winning position, so the evaluation is always 0.

There is no obvious issue with your implementation of the minimax, however your evaluation function is too simple.

You can, for example:

- Give more points to playing in a position that creates a row of 2
- Give more points to playing in a position that creates multiple rows of 2
- Give less points to a position that is already blocked

However, there is only so much you can do. This game is obviously solved, and a perfect player can always get a draw playing either sides.

Comment: thank you, but it made no difference at all

Comment: well, this is a solved problem after all, so in all likelihood, the output of your evaluation function will always be 0. You can try to evaluate positions that you know are winning or loosing, like `[x,x,-], [x,-,-],[-,-,-]` (it's invalid for the purpose of the game, but it `o` is the next player, they can't win, and if `x` is the next player they can't loose. That should demonstrate that your evaluation function works, and that your minimax is correctly implemented too. But in any case, this game is not the right target for this algorithm, as it should always result in a draw.